# VB .Net BC30491: Expression does not produce a value

Tags: vb.net

This is my part of code:

```
Imports System
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Threading.Tasks
Imports Proxies
Imports Services
Imports Settings
Imports Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration
Imports Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection
Imports Microsoft.Extensions.Logging

Public Class Program
    Private Shared _serviceProvider As IServiceProvider
    Private Shared _configuration As IConfigurationRoot
    Private Shared _logger As ILogger

    

    Private Shared Sub SetupConfiguration(ByVal environment As String)
        _configuration = New ConfigurationBuilder().SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()).AddJsonFile($"{environment}.settings.json", [optional]:=True, reloadOnChange:=True).AddEnvironmentVariables().Build()
    End Sub

    Private Shared Sub SetupServiceProvider()
        Dim serviceCollection As IServiceCollection = New ServiceCollection()
        serviceCollection.AddSingleton(_configuration)
        Program.ConfigureServices(serviceCollection)
        _serviceProvider = serviceCollection.BuildServiceProvider()
        _logger = _serviceProvider.GetRequiredService(Of ILogger(Of Program))()
    End Sub

    Private Shared Sub ConfigureServices(ByVal services As IServiceCollection)
        services.AddLogging(Function(opt) opt.AddConsole())
        services.AddMemoryCache()
        services.Configure(Of AuthorizationSettings)(Function(s) _configuration.GetSection(NameOf(AuthorizationSettings)).Bind(s))
        services.Configure(Of ServicesSettings)(Function(s) _configuration.GetSection(NameOf(ServicesSettings)).Bind(s))
        services.AddSingleton(Of ITokenService, TokenCacheService)()
        services.AddSingleton(Of IIdentityServiceProxy, IdentityServiceProxy)()
        services.AddSingleton(Of IIdentityImportService, CsvIdentityImportService)()
    End Sub
End Class
```

I got the error in these two lines and do not let me compile:

```
services.Configure(Of AuthorizationSettings)(Function(s) _configuration.GetSection(NameOf(AuthorizationSettings)).Bind(s))
services.Configure(Of ServicesSettings)(Function(s) _configuration.GetSection(NameOf(ServicesSettings)).Bind(s))
```

The error I got is this:

```
BC30491:  Expression does not produce a value
```

Any ideas on how to fix it?.  I use this code to connect to an API using OAuth 2.0 and JSON Web Token (JWT) AuthorizationSettings and ServiceSettings are two classes which return configuration.  This code was converted from a C# code

Comment: Change `Function(s)` to `Sub(s)` ... the error is saying that when you use a function, you expect a value to be returned, however, your expression does **not** return a value, hence you should be using a sub

Comment: thanks it worked!!!